# ModifiedNodeDoesNotExistException ODL while writing statistic to operational datastore

Tags: opendaylight

Scenario is application is writing data directly to device and after 4 seconds they are writing to config datastore. Now in the time gap there is statistic collection triggered which will collect the data written and will write it to operational datastore.

My question is whether the data should be present in config datastore before statistic is collected or before the same data is being written to operational datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying which ODL release you are using, nor (more importantly) which application features you have installed are using, but when you write "statistic collection triggered" that sounds like `openflowplugin` project related?  I wonder if https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/66207/ which was proposed just today (not yet reviewed and merged) has anything to do with your problem, and may fix it... If not, you would need to provide more details about you are writing to - as far as I understand, the `ModifiedNodeDoesNotExistException` basically just means something like that what you want to write to meanwhile was concurrently already removed.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am experiencing this in carbon, nitrogen branches. This is in OFP but more importantly i would like to understand the yang tools code part which throws this exception.
you can refer this link : https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/jenkins092/netvirt-csit-1node-openstack-ocata-gate-stateful-nitrogen/122/odl1_karaf.log.gz to get the context.  This is CSIT run on Nitrogen.
method checkTouchApplicable() checks for
modification.getOrginal().isPresent() and cureent.isPresent() in 
AbstractNodeContainerModificationStrategy.java. 
I would be interested to know current tree

Comment: OK then if c/66207 does not help I would try to raise it for further discussion on openflowplugin-dev? I understand very little about openflowplugin internals, but if you see ModifiedNodeDoesNotExistException a lot, then this to me would indicate a conurrency issue in its code - if it often tries to modify data that just deleted, then it may be missing some synchronization, somewhere? Not sure why you are looking inside the low level yangtools AbstractNodeContainerModificationStrategy... to know the current TX tree, why not just read what you want to see at application (openflowplugin) level?

Comment: I was able to fix this on carbon and further releases, it was OFP bug while processing the statistics. Thanks @vorburger for your help.